# Facebook login fails on Chrome. No dialog and Javascript uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this javascript for logging into Facebook:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{{ app_id }}', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'unknown') {
                FB.login({
                    scope: 'friends_birthday,manage_pages'
                });
            }else{
                // Check permissions
                FB.api('/me/permissions',function(response) {
                    if (!('friends_birthday' in response.data[0] && 'manage_pages' in response.data[0])){
                         // Permissions not OK
                         FB.ui({
                            method: 'permissions.request',
                            perms: 'friends_birthday,manage_pages'
                            },function(response) {
                         });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

No dialogs appear and I get a javascript error of an uncaught exception (named "h" apparently) on line 76 of [all.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js).

This occurs on Chrome but not Safari. What is causing the issue?

Comment: Chrome and Facebook don't seem to play nicely together. I've currently got an issue where I can't get `https://facebook.com` to load at all in Chrome on my machine. There are loads of discussions about ths, but I haven't been able to find a solution other than "nuke your Chrome user profile."

Comment: Well I've used many websites that have Facebook functionality and work just fine on Chrome.

Comment: @MatthewMitchell, do you have any extensions, such as Facebook Disconnect, installed? Do you get the same error when running in an incognito window? Also, are you testing this from a local html file or from page hosted on a server? There can be issues in the `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net..."` line when your starting protocol is `file:` (instead of `http[s]:`).

Comment: No extensions are being used. I'm using a local server with HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because of your FB.login function which is wrong, here is a little fix / example:

```
 FB.login(function(responseAuth) {
     if (!responseAuth.authResponse) {
         console.log('Something went wrong...');
         return false;
     }
 }, { scope: 'email' });
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Though I had a problem with blocked pop-ups so I'm now using a redirect to www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth.